# Is there a function that will automatically center a flextable within a specific content placeholder?

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I need to center a flextable based on the dimensions of the content placeholder. Is there a function or method that supports this?

Passing coordinate arguments to ph_location_label() does not appear to work

```
ph_with(ft, location = ph_location_label("Content_Placeholder")

ph_with(ft, location = ph_location_label("Content_Placeholder", left = 2, top = 2))
```

I was expecting this to adjust the top left coordinate of the flextable but both lines of code return the same result where the flextable starts in the top left corner of the content placeholder.